# Random Numbers Array not working in the javascript

Tags: javascript, random, element

i have javascript Array

```
var Numbers = [ 1,2,3];
document.write (Numbers[ Math.floor( Math.random( ) * 3 ) ] );
```

i want to put it into the URL
Like this:

```
"//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId= + Numbers + ";
```

i want to show random numbers after appId=

Comment: `"//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=" + Numbers`;

Comment: can you please give me the demo on JSfiddle ?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/yotije/1/edit?js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't work with `Numbers` as a single number while it's an array. First generate random number `n`, then put that into FB link.

```
var Numbers = [1,2,3];
var n = Numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
var link = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=" + n; 

// alert(link);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8u3b8q1x/

Update due to the comments below:

```
<script> 
var Numbers = [1,2]; 
var n = Numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)]; 

(function(d, s, id) { 
    var js, 
        fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; 

    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    } 

    js = d.createElement(s); 
    js.id = id; 
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=" + n; 
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); 
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')); 

FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', data: n, message: davet_m, title: davet_t, to: string}); 
// here should be probably 'data: js.src' instead of 'data: n', I don't know FB API.

// where are defined davet_m, davet_t, string variables?
</script>
```

Comment: i want to put "n" into this script FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests', data: '+ n +', message: davet_m, title: davet_t, to : string}

Comment: Then remove quotes and plus signs around the `n` variable. `FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', data: n, message: davet_m, title: davet_t, to: string}`

Comment: @user3662085: What does it mean, 'not working'? Any errors in JS console? Are you sure you wanted to put there `n` and not `link` variable? Syntax is correct, you have to need more info. In `link` is what you wanted to achieve in your question, `n` is just number 1-3.

Comment: @user3662085: There is missing bracked `)` at the end, I worked with the code you sent into comment. `FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', data: n, message: davet_m, title: davet_t, to: string});` or `FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', data: link, message: davet_m, title: davet_t, to: string});`.

Comment: its fb invite script.. when i put n in the script then the onclick function not working

Comment: @user3662085: Check you JS syntax. Remove last bracket in `n` declaration, like `var n = Numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];`. Then add bracket behind `FB.ui` as I wrote in comment above.

Comment: @user3662085: I've updated my answer, try this code and see the errors in console if it's still not working. Then, there are any undefined variables in your code, I put them into comment in my asnwer above.Check them if exist.

Comment: @user3662085: JS console says what?

Comment: this onclick method not working when i put n on the script... <a href="#" onClick="sendRequestToFriends('test , - invite your friends','')">Click here</a>

Comment: @user3662085: check the FB API reference. In the short code you wrote above is JS syntax error.

Comment: (index):259 Uncaught ReferenceError: sendRequestToFriends is not defined

Comment: @user3662085: undefned function, fine. Did you define that? No. Check the FB API reference where and how this function should be defined.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: n is not defined(index):222 (anonymous function)(index):224 (anonymous function)
(index):394 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

Comment: There is strange indentation, re-indent the code as you want/need, but it works now. http://jsfiddle.net/8u3b8q1x/4/

Comment: woho0o! its working perfect .... i have low experience with javascripts but thank yOu sO much mate yOu help me!!! ...

Comment: @halfer my web hosting suspended due to high usage of cpu.. Can you please tell me what is wrong with this script??

Comment: @user3662085: your host is unlikely to have suspended your account because of the script supplied by panther. This script is JavaScript, and so probably does not run on your server - it runs on a browser, which the host is not affected by.